# Finding the solution to this specific recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

What would be the solution to $a_n = 7a_{n−2} + 6a_{n−3}$ with $a_0 = 9$,
$a_1 = 10$, and $a_2 = 32$

I can find it for a specific value of (n), but not for just a general solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Still open for a non-generating function answer!

Comment: Ok, done. :) The generating function approach requires solving exactly the same characteristic function, but its advantage is apparently that you don't have to solve a system of equations to account for the initial conditions.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR just want to make sure that these two answers don't contradict each other - mind giving this a look? http://gyazo.com/bf0f0684693bcb9a2b3fb7c1590beeb9  Thanks!

Comment: I've replied to the comment on my answer: that linked image is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the general theory of such linear recurrence relations, the solutions to $a_n = 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3}$ will all be of the form $a_n = c_1 r_1^n + c_2r_2^n + c_3r_3^n$, where $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are all solutions to $r^n = 7r^{n-2} + 6r^{n-3}$, i.e. to $r^3 = 7r + 6$. This is called the characteristic equation.

It turns out (or you can find by trial and error) that the solutions to the characteristic equation are $-1$, $-2$, and $3$.

So we have $a_n = c_1(-1)^n + c_2(-2)^n + c_33^n$. Putting your initial conditions given, namely $a_0 = 9$, $a_1 = 10$, and $a_2 = 32$, we get the equations

$$\begin{aligned}
c_1 + c_2 + c_3 &= 9 \\
-c_1 - 2c_2 + 3c_3 &= 10 \\
c_1 + 4c_2 + 9c_3 &= 32
\end{aligned}$$
solving which gives $c_1 = 8$, $c_2 = -3$, and $c_3 = 4$. So $a_n = 8(-1)^n - 3(-2)^n + 4(3)^n$.

Comment: Hmm..are you sure this is right?

Comment: This seems to contradict this method: http://gyazo.com/bf0f0684693bcb9a2b3fb7c1590beeb9

Comment: @jtm22: Yes I'm sure this is right. Just put $n = 3$ to check: the recurrence relation $a_n = 7a_{n-2} + 6a_{n-3}$ gives $a_3 = 7a_1 + 6a_0 = 7(10) + 6(9) = 124$. My expression $a_n = 8(-1)^n - 3(-2)^n + 4(3)^n$ gives $a_3 = -8 - 3(-8) + 4(27) = 124$, while the linked (wrong) solution $a_n = 3 + 5(2^n) + (-3)^n$ gives $a_3 = 3 + 5(8) + (-27) = 16$, which is wrong.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: I just checked it with a spreadsheet and it solves the problem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, and write the recurrence as:
$$
a_{n + 3} = 7 a_{n + 1} + 6 a_n \quad a_0 = 9, a_1 = 10, a_2 = 32
$$
By properties of ordinary generating funtions:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - a_2 z^2}{z^3} = \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} + 6 A(z)
$$
Writing as partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = 4 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} 
        - 3 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + 2 z} 
        + 8 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + z}
$$
Expanding the various geometric series:
$$
a_n = 4 \cdot 3^n - 3 \cdot (-2)^n + 8 \cdot (-1)^n
$$

Comment: I am not familiar with generating functions, although you seem to live by them vonbrand! Haha, could we use another way possibly?

Comment: @jtm22, there certainly are other ways. This is just by far the simplest.

Comment: What is the characteristic equation?

Comment: @jtm22, $(1 - 3 z) (1 + 2 z) (1 + z)$

Comment: Thanks.  You wouldn't mind solving it with regular characteristic equations, though, would you?

Comment: @jtm22, yes, I would. This method is much more general, and less work.